# Replacing multiple lines in sed or awk

Tags: sed, awk, scripting, perl

I'm trying to use sed or awk to replace 5 lines in a smb file but I just don't have any idea how to deal with the newlines.

Comment: f course, sed and awk can do this, but I'm having a little trouble understaning exactly what your question is. What exactly is causing you trouble? Inserting new lines? Replacing them?

Answer (score 23):

Sed is quite bad at this, because it operates one line at a time. The only decent technique I've ever seen to do this is [this one](http://austinmatzko.com/2008/04/26/sed-multi-line-search-and-replace/), which involves storing the entire file in sed's hold buffer and then operating on it all at once:

```
sed -n '1h;1!H;${g;s/search/replace/;p;}'
```

---

If you can, it's much easier to use perl to accomplish this:

```
perl -0pe 's/search/replace/'
```

`search` can contain `\n`s to represent newlines

Comment: +1 for the `sed` multiliner.

Comment: Can you explain what the command line args to perl do?

Comment: @Michael `-0` sets the record separator to null, so the whole file will be read at once instead of line-by-line. `-p` makes it print the result after the substitution. `-e` has it take the next argument as the expression to run, and `s/search/replace/` is that expression